# Getting custom data from Paypal

Tags: paypal

I am creating a simple online paypal commerce and I have some doubts 
on how sending data to seller and buyer when order payment is done. The 
scenario looks like this:

Each product (legal documents) has a different form because in order to 
deliver the product buyer need to specify different information for each
item. Studying Paypal documentation I have learnt that I can add hidden
fields and send them with transaction when I click the Buy Button or Add
To Cart.

When the payment is done:

1. buyer will receive the confirmation of payment (ok sent by paypal)
2. seller will receive all necessary information to fill the documents 
   for each product in one email.

I have noticed using sandbox that buyyer can add note for seller with payment
but unfortunatlly the textarea allow only a limitated text.

Please let me know if I understand correctly. When the payment is done Paypal
send back all data (IPN) to paypal script (including all information sent via
using the form). In that case I should be able to check if the transaction was
completed and if so doing the parser of the reply and send data via email using
PHP to seller. Is it correct?

Does anyone can show me a simple example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When transaction is complete (subscription,one time web form payment,express checkout or something else ) , Paypal sends authorization query to your IPN script (link to which is defined in your Paypal profile)
The IPN values are described here
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html

or here

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

Comment: Thanks. But in my case it looks different. I want to send with each product my own input field like (numofpage, typeoflat....). Then when the payment is done (both cart and single item) ipn script should parse the answer and if the transaction is completed seller will received an email with all extra data specified by the buyer. Having these information the buyer then is able to provide the legal documents. I have seen that I can add extra custom fild in paypal form button but it seems that i cannot change its name. It can be only "custom". :((

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to accomplish it?

Comment: You could pass several values in the "custom" field. For example, you can run something like base64_encode("val1,val2,val3"). Why does it make a difference, how a field is called?

Comment: Hi. Well some fields have the same name even if they belong to different form (each form is a single product) but I could change it. For example one form is called IDCard. I guess there are limitation regarding the number of custom fields and max size allowed :(